# TypeError: this.$refs.datasource.fetch is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-vue

I am trying to call the [fetch](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/fetch) method on a data source created with [a vue wrapper](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/datasource/datasource/data-binding/).

The error is **[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.datasource.fetch is not a function"** So my question is how can I call methods from the $refs object.

I made a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/saeqlu)

```
<body>
    <div id="vueapp" class="vue-app">
        <kendo-datasource ref="datasource" :data="dataSourceArray">
        </kendo-datasource>
    </div>
</body>

new Vue({
    el: '#vueapp',
    data: function() {
        return {
            dataSourceArray: [
                { text: 'Albania', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Andorra', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Armenia', value: '3' },
                { text: 'Austria', value: '4' },
                { text: 'Azerbaijan', value: '5' },
                { text: 'Belarus', value: '6' },
                { text: 'Belgium', value: '7' }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.$refs.datasource.fetch()//<== error here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref you are getting is the entire `<kendo-datasource>` component, which does not directly have a `fetch()` method. I believe what you are trying to do is get the kendoDataSource within the component and call the fetch method on it, which would be:

```
this.$refs.remoteDatasource.kendoDataSource.fetch();
```

modifying your example to see it in action:

```
    <kendo-datasource 
        ref="datasource" 
        :data="dataSourceArray" 
        :type="'odata'"
        :transport-read-url="'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers'">
    </kendo-datasource>
```

```
this.$refs.remoteDatasource.kendoDataSource.fetch(function(){
    var data = this.data();
    console.log(data[0]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. While I was googling I also found another way to get the `kendoDataSource` object by calling `this.$refs.datasource.kendoWidget()`